# SEO Question - HTTP versus HTTPS?

Tags: seo

When getting indexed by search engines, is there a difference if the public side of a site is served via HTTPS or via HTTP?

I am trying to optimize my site so that all search engines can find the site.

http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/index.htm

Comment: Was it necessary to mention what site are you trying to optimize?

Comment: Is there any significant reason to wrap your entire site in HTTPS? Are you worried that evil Communists will read your public pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the search engines should index your site as normal even if it's under SSL/HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You should pick one only either the http or the https.

301 is probably best here. There are two tricks here, though, and it can get messy:

(1) You'll need to link to the HTTPS version in your internal links as well.

(2) If you use relative links (like "/about.aspx"), then all the navigation links from your secure home-page will cause Google to crawl the rest of the site with HTTPS, possibly creating mass dupe content.

Practically, there's a fair amount of risk in just securing your home-page, and it goes beyond the home-page itself. I'd proceed with caution and really evaluate the pros and cons.

You can read more below:

[duplicate content and http and https](http://www.seomoz.org/q/duplicate-content-and-http-and-https)

and

[SEO for HTTP and HTTPs](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-for-http-and-https/15055/)